# How to check if logs has 7 consecutive days?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

## Objective

Below is the example data format. I need to get the in day 1, 2, 3, and so on.. On each account.

```
+------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+--------------+-----+
| m_idPlayer |   Start_Time   |    End_Time    | TotalPlayTime |   account    | SEQ |
+------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+--------------+-----+
|    0000001 | 20170202131759 | 20170202132311 |           312 | developer    |   1 |
|    0000001 | 20170202132351 | 20170202132615 |           144 | developer    |   2 |
|    0000001 | 20170202135834 | 20170202141342 |           908 | developer    |   3 |
|    0000002 | 20170202141645 | 20170202141814 |            89 | runewars21   |   4 |
|    0000003 | 20170202142341 | 20170202142559 |           138 | speedyturtle |   5 |
|    0000004 | 20170202142700 | 20170202142756 |            56 | kevlaire05   |   6 |
|    0000005 | 20170202142915 | 20170202143225 |           190 | infinity13   |   8 |
|    0000003 | 20170202142609 | 20170202143225 |           376 | speedyturtle |   9 |
|    0000002 | 20170202141820 | 20170202143721 |          1141 | runewars21   |  10 |
|    0000001 | 20170202142821 | 20170202143742 |           561 | developer    |  11 |
+------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+--------------+-----+
```

- I need to check on that record if the user has logged in and played with a specific total play time (example: Day 1 - required to play  for 2 hours)
- Also check if the user has logged in for the consecutive days.

## Example expected results where account is developer

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| account   | player  | Day 1     | Day 2      | And so on |
+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| developer | 0000001 | 1925 secs | null       |           |
+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Give your expected output as well.

Comment: I've added the expected results

Comment: also see the link referenced to know on  how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: sorry newbie here. Thank you for the guide

Comment: Is the expected result inline with your sample data? If `20170204` is `Day 1`, how do you have expected result for `Day 4`. Also for `Day 1` for `Kamuka`, how do you get `6 hours`?

Comment: No, it's just an example.

Comment: Give the expected result based on the sample data, not some example

Comment: @Utsav I've updated the data and expected results